# Subquery in CASE expression in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I'm new here and really not so well known in PostgreSQL.

I have two tables (table usages which are aggregated per month and table customer_dunnings which shows historical all customers dunning_level and dunning_date). I need to show customers which has violated_usages in the last 3 months (this I could solve). But I would need to show as well if the customer had a dunning_level and if yes, which level he had in that month.

In table usages I have column datetime which comes as date like this '2019-09-01', as aggregated it's always showing first day of month. On table customer_dunnings I have column dunning_date which comes as date like this '2019-09-15' showing the exact date when customer reached a dunning level and which dunning_level.

I want to display the dunning_level in case a customer had a dunning_level on that usages.datetime.

I thought with a CASE expression I could do that.

Here is my Query. Hope you can help me with that.

```
SELECT  
u.id,  
u.datetime,  
to_char(u.datetime, 'YYYYMM') "month",  
u.customer_id,  
u.customer_number CID,   
case when u.customer_number in (select c.customer_number 
                                from v_reporting_customer_dunnings d 
                                left join v_reporting_cids c on c.customer_id=d.customer
                                left join usages u on u.customer_number=c.customer_number and to_char(u.datetime, 'YYYYMM')=to_char(d.dunning_date, 'YYYYMM')) then 'yes' else null end as dunning  
FROM usages u
```

example customer on table usages:

```
ID          Datetime    Month   Customer_ID   CID        Dunning  
11306415573 2019-09-01  201909  2039145295    80035006   yes
8208810439  2018-12-01  201812  2039145295    80035006   yes
7926569969  2018-11-01  201811  2039145295    80035006   yes
7654669868  2018-10-01  201810  2039145295    80035006   yes
```

example customer on table v_reporting_customer_dunnings:

```
Customer    INVOICE     DUNNING_LV  INVOICE_DT  DUNNING_DT  
2039145295  90354914    LEVEL 10    2018-09-30  2018-11-16  
2039145295  90226540    LEVEL 10    2018-04-30  2018-06-08
```

example customer on table v_reporting_cids:

```
Customer_ID Customer_Number    
2039145295  80035006      
2039145295  80035006
```

This customer had 2 times a dunning level. 1x it was in the same year-month as in table usages. in this case in my query should be a column giving me the dunning_level for the matching year-month.

what I expect/would like to have:

```
ID          Datetime    Month   Customer_ID   CID       Dunning   Dunning_Level
11306415573 2019-09-01  201909  2039145295    80035006  NULL      NULL
8208810439  2018-12-01  201812  2039145295    80035006  NULL      NULL
7926569969  2018-11-01  201811  2039145295    80035006  yes       LEVEL 10
7654669868  2018-10-01  201810  2039145295    80035006  NULL      NULL
```

Comment: Please add some minimized sample data and the expected output!

Comment: What is wrong with your query? Do you get the wrong answers? An error message? Please give details.

Comment: no error message just not what I expect. with the last case when with subquery I would like to know if at the usages.datetime customer had a dunning_level. actually like this he always shows 'yes' when customer is in table v_reporting_customer_dunnings. It is not checking if the date is matching.

Comment: Please read the help section [ask]. Following that as a template for your question vastly improves your chance of getting a satisfactory answer. In this case it's especially difficult as you failed to describe tables and the data provide does not correspond the the columns used in the query. In the users table what's the difference between customer_number and customer_id (both used). Also no description or data provided for table v_reporting_cids. And your selecting several columns from the usages table with no data is provided. Please provide sample data for at least all referenced columns.

Comment: @Belayer Thank you for your response and time. I have corrected my text and I hope now it is more clear.